# Start-Service does not return enough information about the failure

Tags: c#, powershell, windows-services, .net-core-3.1

The problem is that when I start the Windows service from under the `OctopusDeploy`, then if the service fails to starts - the error message is not descriptive enough.. I am using the `.net core 3.1` and the `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices` package to create a windows service. It is easy to reproduce the issue locally:

`Start-Service MySvc`

following error is shown from the `PowerShell`

> Start-Service : Service 'MySvc (MySvc)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service MySvc on computer '.'. At line:1 char:1
>
> Start-Service MySvc
>
> ```
> + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
>
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
> ```

**As you see it is lacking any information about the error message.**

The builder looks like this:

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseWindowsService()
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.DoCustomLogic();
                services.AddHostedService<Mysvc>();
            })
            .ConfigureLogging(loggingBuilder =>
            {
                loggingBuilder
                    .AddConsole(options => { options.IncludeScopes = true; })
                    .AddEventLog();
            });
```

In fact, I know for sure, what kind of exception is thrown in method `DoCustomLogic()` (actual code is cleaned-up for simplicity):

```
    public static void DoCustomLogic(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        string exMsg = "my custom exception";
        throw new Exception(exMsg);
    }
```

Also, after start failure - in the `Event Viewer` there are 2 new records:
[image]
The `.Net runtime` outputs:

```
Application: MySvc.exe
CoreCLR Version: 4.700.19.60701
.NET Core Version: 3.1.1
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Exception: my custom exception
...
```

**`Exception Info: System.Exception: my custom exception`**

So basically, I am the one who is actually throwing an exception and I know exactly what the error is. My question is - is this possible to output some more meaningful information into the `powershell` console about this kind of exception?

For the users who are using the `Octopus Deploy` - it is counter intuitive that there is no actual error message displayed in logs, so they have to log-into the server and check the event viewer logs.

I guess one possible solution would be to create a post-build script that would check the events.. but I would rather solve it with C# if possible..

Comment: I'm no expert, but it doesn't sound unreasonable that `Start-Service` will only check the service started successfully or not. Services can have any kind of process behind them, not only `.net` processes, so I don't see why there'd be a mechanism that allows a `.net` exception to be thrown all the way back up the various APIs to the entity or process starting the service. The event log is indeed the right place for this info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up creating `octopus deploy` script that prints last 3 errors from the Windows events.

```
$EntryType = 'Error'
$LogName = 'Application'
$Source = '.NET Runtime'
$EventCount = 3

Write-Host ' '
Write-Host "Searching for the last $EventCount events of source $Source.."
$evts = Get-EventLog -LogName $LogName -Newest $EventCount -EntryType $EntryType -Source $Source -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue # | Format-List -Property *
if($evts){
    Write-Host ' '
    $i = 1;
    $evts | ForEach-Object -Process {
        Write-Host "`tPrinting event $i"

        $obj = $_#$evts | Select-Object -Property TimeGenerated, Message
        $time = $obj."TimeGenerated"
        $message = $obj."Message" # or $obj | Select -ExpandProperty "SomeProp"

        Write-Host "`tTime: $time"
        Write-Host "`tMessage: $message"
        Write-Host ' '
        $i++;
    }

} else{
    Write-Host "No events found with the name $Source"
}

Write-Host ' '
Exit 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I cannot test it for you, but what about adding `-ErrorAction Stop` and catching the exception?

```
try {
    Start-Service MySvc -ErrorAction Stop
} catch {
    # Examine and play with one of the following objects
    Write-Host "$($error[0].Exception)"
    Write-Host "$($_.exception)"
}
```

Comment: the same message is shown unfortunately as described previously..